# Passing output-values from a C-program to MATLAB (via batch-file)

Tags: matlab, batch-file

I have a DOS batch-file `MYDOS.BAT` containing:

1. My C-application (`myApp.exe`) reading an input-file (`inputFile`) from the DOS-command line
2. `myApp.exe` analyses `inputFile` and exits/returns with a code=`N`
3. How can I pass value `N` into my MATLAB script?

E.g: `MYDOS.BAT` is run by `DOS>MYDOS inputFile` and contains the following lines:

```
myApp %1
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
set samplerate=%ERRORLEVEL%
echo %samplerate%
...
C:/... matlab mymatlab.m ...
```

HOW CAN I THEN PASS the value `%samplerate%` into my `mymatlab.m` script?

Comment: It is _not_ **DOS**, it is **Windows** command prompt! **DOS** is an OS from the 1980's...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `system` command to use DOS commands in Matlab. Use `doc system` to see the documentation.

System can have 2 outputs. The first one is a status, which will tell you if the operation succeeded. The second one is the output to the command prompt. You can parse this to get your value. You could use the following code as a guide for your situation:

`[status,cmdout]=system('MYDOS.bat');`

`cmdout` will contain the string that you are echoing to the command prompt.